# Postfix: restrict all external access but allow for only mynetworks

Tags: email, postfix

How can I restrict access for an internal domain but allow all access for me the administrator? All users should be blocked from communicating outbound and no external domain may contact them, but I should be able to receive emails from any domain and send to any domain.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me at least. A recipient domain doesn't belong in `mynetworks` or not, it just is. You can match the connecting IP against `mynetworks` using e.g. `permit_mynetworks`, but that's about the best you can do with only Postfix. You *could* write a custom policy service and use that, which could implement basically arbitrary business logic for accepting/rejecting a mail transaction; is that what you are after? If it is, please [edit] your question to indicate that.

Comment: My question has been edited